# c# caching meta data content causes Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, garbage-collection

In an application there is a class that controls the cache of some data that is constantly reused.

We have had this code working for about a year, but lately, as the application (asp.net mvc 5) grows, it is throwing an error

> Index was outside the bounds of the array when attempting to add more
>   data into it

It was fixed by restarting the IIS server.

How could we improve / modify this code to avoid the error?

```
public class DataCache
{
    private static Dictionary<string, CacheEntry> _cacheEntries = new Dictionary<string, CacheEntry>();

    public static bool Exists(string cacheId)
    {
        // Check if cache entry is valid.
        if (_cacheEntries.ContainsKey(cacheId) && DateTime.UtcNow < _cacheEntries[cacheId].CacheUntil)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static object Get(string cacheId)
    {
        // Return entry.
        if (_cacheEntries.ContainsKey(cacheId))
            return _cacheEntries[cacheId].Data;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public static void Put(object cacheObj, string cacheId, DateTime cacheUntil)
    {
        // Create new cache entry.
        CacheEntry e = new CacheEntry()
        {
            Data = cacheObj,
            CacheUntil = cacheUntil
        };

        // Delte pre-existing items.
        if (_cacheEntries.ContainsKey(cacheId))
            _cacheEntries.Remove(cacheId);

        // Insert it into cache.
        _cacheEntries.Add(cacheId, e);
    }

    class CacheEntry 
    {
        public object Data;
        public DateTime CacheUntil;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not thread-safe. More use/more traffic = concurrency problems. Look at the built in caching mechanisms and the concurrent collections already in .Net.

Comment: Where exactly you're getting the error, debug or trace or write to log file with details and find the statement, that way its easy. That means its not locating the value in the specified index. As it was old system you cant rewrite whole but at least you can try to log the error details with stack trace.

Comment: Hi Tim, do you have a clue where I can find more info about the built in caching functionality?

Comment: Venkata, error happens on line _cacheEntries.Add(cacheId, e); when inserting new data. It happens every roughly 2 days.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.100).aspx - you could also modify your existing code to use `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, but I'd stick with the "out of the box" functionality already available in the `Cache` class if you aren't familiar with writing multithreaded code.

Comment: Go through this [How to: Add Items to the Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/18c1wd61(v=vs.100).aspx) you can have idea on built in caching